# Speakers are not working after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, dell, dell-vostro

The day before yesterday I upgraded my OS from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04.
And I was able to hear sound from my "DELL VOSTRO - 3400" Laptop for 24 hours only.

But after that sound is coming through the headset only, not through speakers.

I searched for solution and followed the instruction given in the [Sound troubleshooting help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure).

I have run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio
rm -r ~/.pulse*
sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group |
  grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' |
  awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`

wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh

bash alsa-info.sh --stdout 
# resulted in different driver version: 1.0.24 (which actually should be 1.0.25)

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily;sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get install alsa-hda-dkms.

cat /proc/asound/{version,cards,devices,hwdep,pcm,seq/clients}
sudo rm /etc/asound.conf
sudo rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound*
sudo rm ~/.pulse-cookie
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install paman gnome-alsamixer libasound2-plugins padevchooser libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio
sudo lshw -short
ls -lart /dev/snd
cat /dev/sndstat
lspci -nn
lsusb
sudo which alsactl
sudo fuser -v /dev/dsp /dev/snd/*
dpkg -S bin/slmodemd
dmesg | egrep 'EMU|probe|emu|ALSA|alsa|ac97|udi|snd|ound|irmware'
sudo /etc/init.d/sl-modem-daemon status
sudo grep model /etc/modprobe.d/*
sudo dmidecode|egrep 'anufact|roduct|erial|elease'
lsmod | egrep 'snd|usb|midi|udio'
aplay -l
sudo alsa force-reload
sudo lshw -C sound
```

Then I rebooted the system. But still I am not getting any sound through the speakers. Have I omitted some commands or anything else?

Comment: I have the same laptop. When you open sound settings do you see two viable outputs just the one?

Comment: Yes , I have tested both the ends of speaker, but none of them is working.  :(

Comment: Plase dear friends help me out. Till today I have not got any solution ?

Comment: I am facing the same problem? Did you solve it? if so please share it as an answer. Someone else will be helpful

Comment: @Shiplu , till today I haven't got my problem solved. I think I have to reinstall 12.04 again.I know it is not the actual solution.In worst case I have to do so. Please post the solution if you are able to find it out.

Comment: I did a lot of things. But after issuing `sudo alsa reload` it seems fixed.

Comment: Thanks Shiplu... But in my system it is not working. :(

Comment: once i had a similar problem but it was just because 'Line Jack Sense' was not checked in alsa mixer  --- just maybe ---

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that the pulsaudio settings get messed up in upgrades sometimes.

try removing the .pulse or .pulseaudio folder in your home folder and restarting.
or at least move it some place else allowing pulseaudio to generate a new configs if any are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to play with alsamixer? Run alsamixer and then see if any of the outputs is muted (has MM). Press `m` to mute/unmute the channel.